# Reducing the number of IOPS - Performance improvement question

Tags: java, performance, architecture

so I have an application that is processing a large text document which is composed of many logical documents. Say for eg it has 200,000 logical documents. Right now I read one logical document and do the transformation and write logical document out. This works well because nothing is stored in memory so the workflow ends up finishing fast but the number of IOPS end up being high! Is there any recommendation on how I can reduce the number of IOPS ?

Comment: Read more each time? Wrap your file IO in something reading and caching larger blocks - and your writing could lazy flush when cached data exceeds some threshold

Comment: How are you doing the reading and writing?  Since you've tagged this Java, the obvious suggestion would be to use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: Yeah am using buffInputStream and BuffOutputStream and I need to process one file before I could process the next ...

Comment: as Jonathan said, I don't think you're going to get any better advice without being more specific or actually showing some code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a single pass through the document, increase your read buffer size (i.e. 2 reads with a buffer size of 1024 becomes 1 read with a buffer size of 2048, which means less overhead).

If you want more detailed suggestions, you'll need to provide more details in your question.